# Issue when making migration with Doctrine ManyToMany definition

Tags: doctrine, php-8, symfony6

I am using symfony 6 and I am facing an issue when executing the make:migration command, I want actually to bind 2 entities called Team and User.
Below the Team Entity

```php
   #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TeamRepository::class)]
   class Team
   {
       #[ORM\Id]
       #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
       #[ORM\Column]
       private ?int $id = null;

       #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
       private ?string $name = null;

       #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'teams')]
       #[ORM\JoinTable(name: "team_users")]
       #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "uuid")]
       #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: "team_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
       private Collection $members;

       ...
```

And below the User entity:

```php
   #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
   class User
   {
   #[ORM\Id]
   #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
   #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
   #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
   #[Groups([GRP_USER_READ, SerializationGroups::REST])]
   private $uuid;

   #[Groups([GRP_USER_READ, SerializationGroups::REST])]
   #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180, unique: true)]
   #[Assert\NotBlank]
   #[Assert\Email]
   private $email;

   #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
   #[Groups([GRP_USER_READ, SerializationGroups::REST])]
   private $roles = [];

   #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
   private $password;
   
   #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Team::class, mappedBy: 'members')]
   private Collection $teams;

   ...
```

Then, when I clear the cache and launch make:migration, I get directly an exception:

> Column name "uuid" referenced for relation from App\Entity\Team
> towards App\Entity\User does not exist.

After checking everything in the database and the User entity, the field named uuid is the right one.

I'm a bit confused about how php8 attributes work, I took this example from the doctrine documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/attributes-reference.html#manytomany), is there something missing to define that relation properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, actually it was a misunderstanding in the Attributes configuration, I moved the owning side in the User entity and left a single reference in the Team entity, so here's what you get in User:

```php
   #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Team::class, inversedBy: 'members')]
   #[ORM\JoinTable(name: "user_teams")]
   #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "uuid")]
   #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: "team_id", referencedColumnName: "id")]
   private Collection $teams;
```

And in Team:

```php
   #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: "User", mappedBy: 'teams')]
   private Collection $members;
```